# Loop Through Query Result then Determine Whether It is The Value of an Item

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops, conditional-statements

This is all about updating the information on category of an item.

I have the textbox containing the current category of an item and selectbox where the list of available categories can be selected ( take note that this is connected to the database and that the list of categories in the database can be updated).

Example 1:

Item A
Textbox: Cleaning Category

Selectbox:
-Food Category
-Technology Category

Example 2:

Item B
Textbox: Food Category

Selectbox:
-Cleaning Category
-Technology Category

As you can notice whenever the item belongs to that category (example: cleaning category) the choices for categories will not include what is selected (in that case, cleaning category will not be included as it is the selected category.)

Right now my code is this

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$name = $row['name'];
$description = $row['description'];
$price = $row['price'];
$image_path = $row['image_path'];
$category = $row['category'];
$paypal_code = $row['paypal_code'];
?>

Product Name: <?php echo $name ?>"><br><br>
Category: <?php echo $category ?>"><br><br>
<select name="product_category[]">
    <?php
    $result = mysqli_query($db_link, "SELECT * FROM product_category");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $categories = $row['category'];
        ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $categories; ?>">
             <?php echo $categories; ?>
        </option><?php
    }
    ?>
</select><br><br><?php
}
mysqli_close($db_link);
```

But this code doesnt remove the value of category per item in the choicest of categories. Please help, thanks!

Comment: You need to loop with PHP, what you are currently suggesting is impossible using JS. It should either all be processed client-side or server-side - mixing the two is nonsensical.

Comment: You have a point there buddy, now I've made a code using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on the suggestion of @Vld, he said what I need is PHP not jQuery. This is the solution code for my problem.

```
<div id="links">
    <?php
    $img_start = 1;
    $img_end = 19;
    while ($img_start <= $img_end){ ?>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/events_images/2013_Halloween/halloween (<?php echo $img_start?>).JPG">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/events_images/2013_Halloween/halloween (<?php echo $img_start?>).JPG" width="50" height="50">
    </a>

    <?php
    $img_start +=1;
    }
    ?>
</div>
```